# Docker for Windows swarm overlay networking, connecting to the swarm from outside or localhost

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-for-windows

I cannot connect to the published port on the swarm that uses overlay networking. I am using Docker for Windows with Windows containers. Both Windows and Docker are fully upgraded. After Windows' 1709 update, I was hoping this issue would be resolved. I looked for information on the Internet to see if I was doing something wrong to no avail. I would like to know if anyone was successfully able to get it working.

On a side note, when I direct the port on my machine in `docker run -p 80:80` without using swarm, "localhost" does not work as well. I think this is a known limitation though. Both issues work when I switch to Linux containers.

#### Expected behavior

I am running a dotnet kestrel web server service. I should be able to connect to my service using the published port.

#### Actual behavior

Firefox gives me timeout, opera straight away returns connection refused. Cannot telnet into it either. Container IP's assigned by the overlay network do not work either.

#### Information

`docker service ls` gives me this:
[image]
Ports cannot be seen there, is it because publish mode is host? Ports information is available in the output of `docker service ps`
[image] 
And when I change the publish mode, I can scale it as well and the port information is seen in `docker service ls` albeit still cannot connect. the one below is without the `publish mode=host` parameter:
[image]
For more info, this is the output of the `docker network ls` I wonder if i need some sort of bridge network like in Linux.
[image]

#### Steps to reproduce the behavior

1. Initialise swarm
2. Start the service, in my case: a simple web service built using aspnetcore:latest image. I tried different parameters, even used a docker-stack.yml:
    `docker service create --name=web --publish mode=host,published=80,target=80 web:aspnetcorelatest`  in the case above, I was unable to scale it on the same machine, which is normal i guess 
   `docker service create --name=web --publish published=85,target=80 web:aspnetcorelatest`
3. Try to connect using one of `http://localhost` or another IP. I tried connecting over VPN, from another machine as well as Internet IP.

Comment: Did you try to connect to published port from external host to your machine?

Comment: Yes tried that. In fact, I can connect when I use `docker run` to start the container and not use services. Linux containers work fine as well with swarm and all that.

Comment: Check `docker ps` if port is mapped. It shall be in `host` mode

Comment: Port is mapped in host mode, does not work though. Tried with a few different ports, same thing. And I did add the ports as exceptions on firewall and did the necessary adjustments on the router. They work when they are not services i.e. with `docker run -p 80:80 <image>`

Comment: What you `docker ps` shows?

Comment: Shows the port when it is in `host` mode, the same output as `docker service ps web`

Comment: what does `Docker network inspect <network-id-or-name>` show?

Comment: Where should I look at specifically in `docker network inspect`?

Comment: What version/edition of Windows, and version/edition of Docker are you using? Swarm overlay is one of the latest features to work on Windows Server but not sure if it will work on Docker for Windows on Windows 10 Pro with the Hyper-V/localhost stuff.

Comment: Windows 10 pro with 1709 update, fully updated + docker 18.02.0-ce-win52 No hyper-v is involved at the moment, although I will run it in a WinServer16 guest on Hyper-V eventually, when they are updated to 1709 as well.

The weird thing is, I was unable to find anyone successfully implemented swarm on Windows on the Internet :D

Comment: @Yamaç Kurtuluş Did you find some solution to this?

Comment: @dockerdaemon13 not really, I did not care much about it. I plan to upgrade to WS 2019 soon, and will look it, until then, I am stuck with docker-compose for the moment.